# Is "POST /?fgko=vkma" a valid post request?

Tags: php

I have found lots of single requests in my access logs, that is, a "POST" request followed by "/", then a question mark ("?") followed by a few random characters which then equal to more random characters..

For example:

ps485115.dreamhost.com - - [31/Dec/2018:09:53:28 -0600] "POST /?fgko=vkma HTTP/1.1" 403 308 "http://example.com/?fgko=vkma" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"

Sometimes that's the only request to the server that I can see from the ip address who's accessing my site (probably because just like in the example above, according to the access log, the visitor was already blocked).

Comment: What do you mean when you ask if it's valid? There is nothing wrong with passing the data with both GET(query string) & POST(payload).

Comment: @Dharman, "Valid" as in, does it serve any purpose period (legitimate, malicious, benign, etc)? Your assumption that "there is nothing wrong" with passing data such as this makes no sense to me, especially when one has no idea as to why (since most of these data requests come mostly from bots) there are so many of them and at different times of the day. Therefore IP addresses that only come to make that kind of "payload" should then be barred from accessing your site, don't you think? Thanks for your input, anyway.

Comment: From a technical point of view this is a valid request. You said yourself that there is a lot of bot traffic. This might be just some anti cache technique. I would be more worried what was posted to your system? CSRF maybe, or maybe something benign. But if that is your concern then this is not the best place to look for this kind of help.

Comment: From a "technical" point of view this is NOT a valid request because the expression "fgko=vkma" or any combination of characters similar to that is technically speaking meaningless. This site advises to ban any IP addresses found posting these kind of requests because are probably testing your php to no good end: http://averyniceweb.com/support/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=540

Comment: What good does it do to ban an IP address? You would need to ban all IP addresses in existence to make this work. It is definitely a valid request from technical point of view. It doesn't violate any internet standards and could even be a legitimate request. In practical sense it might not have a meaning, but it doesn't mean that it isn't valid technically. It has a well defined meaning, but maybe not in the scope of this particular application.

Comment: The link you have provided contains no real facts and is a very bad recommendation. From security point of view you should design your web application to not accept just any kind of data that is thrown at your server, it should be very picky. While it is up to the server to decide whom they decide to serve the data, blocking IP addresses because the request looked strange is a bad idea, and doesn't make it any more secure.

Comment: [Strange POST requests to server's IP address. Is this security issue?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/179252/strange-post-requests-to-servers-ip-address-is-this-security-issue)
[Elaborate Hacking attempt detected - now what?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42756/elaborate-hacking-attempt-detected-now-what?rq=1)

Comment: I recommend you to move this question to https://security.stackexchange.com/ But first try to search for similar questions before posting. For any security related questions you will get much better answer there than here, StackOverflow is not the best place for this questions.

Comment: Thanks Dharman, I agree this appears to be the wrong place to ask. That said, I also agree with the other site because my shared web account was hacked yesterday and lo and behold who injected the php injection files? Another ip from dreamhost.com. So thanks but I am going to ban any ip's posting this kind of crap.